# HttpListener exception in EndGetContext while closing listener

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httplistener

I have the following simple code to handle one HTTP request in my application. This code works, but, whenever I try to end the application and the close function is called, I get an exception and stack trace that indicates this is happening in the EndGetContext function. How can I avoid this and what is the right way to stop this ? I can of course catch the exception int he waitforrequest function and then shove it under the carpet, but, IMHO this isn't the good way to stop something. As the exception happens in the EndGetContext function, there is nothing I can do afterwards to check if the listener stopped, or set a signal...

```
internal void Run()
{
  m_HttpServer.Prefixes.Add(m_Config.PublicAccessSvcHttpPrefix); 
  m_HttpServer.Start();
  WaitForRequest();
}

private async void WaitForRequest()
{
  HttpListenerContext context = await m_HttpServer.GetContextAsync();
  HandleRequest(context);
  WaitForRequest();
}

internal void HandleRequest(...){...}

internal void Stop()
{
  m_HttpServer.Close();
}

//Handle request function will proccess the incoming request and do som things
```

Comment: So your question is not how to deal with the exception but how to shut down a listener cleanly?

Comment: Correct... IMHO,  if I stop something in a "normal" way, it should not raise an exception, since stopping and starting is not really "exceptional", it should be a normal and common function. The async of course will still return, but then I should be able to check the returned context to see whether it is valid or not and then cleanly exit.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and I solved it by this:

```
m_HttpServer.Stop(); 
m_HttpServer.Close();
```